# How to sum multiple values in a Flux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have expenses data. I need a model that includes the total expense amount, total paid expense amount, and expenses list. For this purpose, I wrote a function named `createExpenseSummaryReport`.

```java
List<ExpenseModel> expensesModel = Arrays.asList(
        new ExpenseModel("Expense1", 121.687, 31.89),
        new ExpenseModel("Expense2", 78.03, 72.5),
        new ExpenseModel("Expense3", 102.014, 102.014),
        new ExpenseModel("Expense4", 100.0, 45.42)
    );
 
....
 public static ExpenseReportSummary createExpenseSummaryReport(List<ExpenseModel> expensesModel) {
    BigDecimal totalExpense = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal totalPaidExpense = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (ExpenseModel expense : expensesModel) {
      totalExpense = totalExpense.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(expense.getAmount()));
      totalPaidExpense =totalPaidExpense.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(expense.getPaidAmount()));
    }
    return new ExpenseReportSummary(expensesModel, totalExpense, totalPaidExpense);
  }
```

In a real project, I have a repository named `IncomeExpenseRepository`. This repository has this method that returns `Flux` income expenses.

```java
Flux<IncomeExpense> byDateContaining = incomeExpenseRepository.findAllByDateContaining(
        request.getPeriod());
```

I need a `createExpenseSummaryReport` service in a reactive way. `createExpenseSummaryReport` includes income-expense list, total income amount, and total paid element. For this purpose, I am trying to complete the below function.

```
@Override
public Mono<IncomeExpenseSummaryReport> getIncomeExpenseReportByPeriod(
GetIncomeExpenseReportRequest request) {

    AtomicReference<BigDecimal> totalExpenseAmount = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    AtomicReference<BigDecimal> totalPaidExpenseAmount = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    
    incomeExpenseRepository.findAllByDateContaining(
            request.getPeriod())
        .doOnEach(d -> {
          IncomeExpense incomeExpense = d.get();
          totalExpenseAmount.getAndSet(BigDecimal.valueOf(incomeExpense.getAmount()));
          if ("paid".equals(incomeExpense.getPaymentStatus())) {
            totalPaidExpenseAmount.getAndSet(BigDecimal.valueOf(incomeExpense.getAmount()));
          }
        });


    return Flux.empty();

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected way to do that is to actually use the [`Flux#reduce`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#reduce-A-java.util.function.BiFunction-) operator:

```java
Flux.just(new ExpenseModel("Expense1", 121.687, 31.89),
        new ExpenseModel("Expense2", 78.03, 72.5),
        new ExpenseModel("Expense3", 102.014, 102.014),
        new ExpenseModel("Expense4", 100.0, 45.42))
    .reduce(new ExpenseReportSummary(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO), ((expenseReportSummary, expenseModel) -> {
        expenseReportSummary.setTotalExpense(
            expenseReportSummary.getTotalExpense().add(BigDecimal.valueOf(expenseModel.getAmount())));
        expenseReportSummary.setTotalPaidExpense(
            expenseReportSummary.getTotalPaidExpense().add(BigDecimal.valueOf(expenseModel.getPaidAmount())));
        return expenseReportSummary;
    }))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
```

The result is a `Mono` of `ExpenseReportSummary`.

Output:

> ExpenseReportSummary(totalExpense=401.731, totalPaidExpense=251.824)